# How can I fix incorrect width of ng-bootstrap datepicker when using bootstrap grid?

Tags: javascript, angular, bootstrap-4, datepicker, ng-bootstrap

I'm using ng-bootstrap date-picker for my Angular 8 project. date-picker is running in pop-up mode. The problem happens when I set the input width using "col-md-6" class, the width of the date-picker increases!

This is my form-group:

```
<div class="form-group col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-12">
  <label class="d-none d-md-block">تـاریخ</label>
  <div class="input-group mb-2">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <button class="input-group-text" type="button" (click)="datePicker1.toggle()"><i
          class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
    </div>
    <input name="date_add" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="تـاریخ" ngbDatepicker
      #datePicker1="ngbDatepicker" [(ngModel)]="dateAddFilter" (dateSelect)="fillCards()" (change)="fillCards()"
      (input)="fillCards()" autocomplete="off" />
  </div>
</div>
```

And the result:
[image]

Comment: If i understand correctly, the problem only happens when you set the size to 6?check if `class="form-group col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3" ` works or not.- Though this is not the answer to your question, may i suggest you to use`ng2-date-picker` instead? it supports Farsi and it has a lot of options.

Comment: col-md-6 is just an example. Setting columns always does this.

Comment: check your .css and the version on ng-bootstrap, and bootstrap.css, I made a stackblitz in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jre5fe?file=app%2Fdropdown-basic.html and work for me.